# Is it possible to have multiple Keycloak realmsconnect to the same icCube server?

Tags: keycloak, iccube

### use case

[image: explanation]

**in icCube**

- one server instance
- icCube users only need to access the reporting
- icCube is used to for a standard reporting solution for an industry vertical and can be used by multiple clients, each having their own (copy of the) structures that work with their own data
- a client can grant one or more users access to their own dashboards in icCube

**authorization requirement**

- it should be possible to link authorization to the client's identity
  management system (such as AD)
- for others, it should be possible to assign a local admin at the client that can give access to their own environment to whom they wih
- for the rest, it should be possible for a centralized admin to maintain access

a perfect job for ...
**keycloak**

- keycloak needs for each of the requirements a seperate realm with client (see picture)

The icCube documentation only makes mention of one Realm & client.

### the question

Is it possible to use multiple keycloak realms & clients with one instance of icCube?

See also [icCube documentation on keycloak integration](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/authentication_keycloak.php)

Answer (score 1):

Right now this is not possible.

The keycloak.json file is used to connect to a Keycloak server that is going to authenticate the HTTP request. So you would need somehow a way to determine which keycloak.json file to use based on the HTTP request before using it meaning having different URL and/or URLs with a specific parameter.

Possibly the multi-tenant support could be extended to be able to configure an authentication logic per tenant with the same constraint about the URL value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Good to know that it could be made possible. Fro now, it is not (yet) requried, but I will come back to you if I need it for a client.